# Multiple ActiveRecord has_many :through associations without introducing instance-dependence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a cycle of associated classes and want to build a has-many-through association on one of them that effectively traverses the cycle in both directions to find the intersection of two other associations.

It's relatively straightforward to do this with an instance-dependent association, but I'd like to be able to eager-load the association (which you can't do with instance-dependent associations).

Here's a minimal case:

```
class UserCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course

  has_many :topics, through: :course

  # I would like to associate all relevant UserTopics to a UserCourse.

  # This doesn't work, as it pulls all Users' UserTopics
  # (I just want this UserCourse's User's UserTopics):
  # has_many :user_topics, through: :topics

  # This works, but is instance-dependent and thus cannot be eager-loaded:
  has_many :user_topics, ->(instance) { where(user_id: instance.user_id) },
    through: :topics
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :topics
  has_many :user_courses  
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :user_topics
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_topics
  has_many :user_courses  
end

class UserTopic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

I feel like it should be possible to do this cleanly with ActiveRecord. Is it?